# Hasse diagrams for sorts of size 3 and 4?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, relations, order-theory, sorting

Does anyone know what does the following mean? I understand that a Hasse diagram 
represents a given partial order but I don't seem to get this example.

Below is a Hasse diagrams for sorts of size 3 and 4.

[image]

Comment: black vs white seem to be distinguishable classes of objects and it looks like the number of possible subsets given the distinction or without it?

Comment: Where are these figures taken from?

Comment: @svsring from here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1r1TFC-C8m_b2huMG5yUHYxRWc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

The diagrams are describing the steps in some sorting algorithm (couldn't tell you which) and giving the resulting partial order at each step in the form of a Hasse diagram. It appears that each case starts with an antichain and ends in a chain.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the link you provided, it's now clear what this diagram is.  The diagram is obtained by collapsing the decision tree of a comparison-based sorting algorithm, as follows.  First draw the decision tree for a sorting algorithm, with the two solid dots in each step representing the two elements that are being compared.  In the resulting decision tree, whenever the left and right subtrees of a node are isomorphic, replace the two subtrees with a single subtree. This gives the collapsed diagram that you have.